# É possível inserir, no mesmo DropdownList, dois resultados? C#

Tags: c#, dropdownlist

No meu código, existe uma página para o cadastro de vendas onde é necessário digitar algumas informações como por exemplo qual cliente fez a compra.

Controller Venda:

```
// GET: Vendas/Create
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "Id", "CPF");
            ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(db.Produtos, "Id", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Vendas/Create
        // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
        // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Data,Fiado,QtdVendida,ValorVenda,ClienteId,ProdutoId")] Venda venda)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Vendas.Add(venda);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "Id", "CPF", venda.ClienteId);
            ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(db.Produtos, "Id", "Nome", venda.ProdutoId);
            logger.Info("Criou uma nova Venda.");
            return View(venda);
        }
```

View Create:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2">Cliente</p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ClienteId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Para isso eu uso um DropDownList que exibe os CPF's dos clientes já cadastrados, porém eu queria saber se nas opções dos CPF's também é possível exibir os nomes dos respectivos clientes ao lado do CPF.

[image: Print do cadastro]

Answer (score 0):

Sim, basta você compor o atributo Text da `SelectList`, digamos que o nome do Cliente esteja na propriedade Nome..

```
var clientesDropList = db.Clientes
                        .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Descricao = $"{x.CPF} - {x.Nome}" })
                        .ToList();

ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(clientesDropList, "Id", "Descricao", venda.ClienteId);
```

Comment: @João Conseguiu resolver?